# (C++) Trouble excluding alphanumeric input into application

Tags: c++

so this is one of the first bits of code I am trying to write without too much direction, however I seem to have hit a wall. I am attempting to write a very basic "MPG" application and one thing I have come to find is that when the application asks for user input it allows inputs such as "2d" or any alphanumeric input and it continues to operate as long as the digit is first. For example "2d will work but "d2" will not, and the application will carry on as if the letter is not there. ex. 2d/2=1.  Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    float a, b;
    char again = 'Y';

    std::cout << "After several hours on the road you wonder what your gas mileage must have been..." << "\n";

    while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
    {
        std::cout << "How much gas did you have in your tank to start with?" << "\n";
        while (!(std::cin >> a))//cin for float a
        {

            std::cout << "Your input must be a number...1" << "\n";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(1000000, '\n');
        }

        if (a > 0)
        std::cout << "How many miles did you travel?" << "\n";

        while (!(std::cin >> b))//cin for float b
        {
            std::cout << "Your input must be a number...2" << "\n";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(1000000, '\n');
        }

        if (b > 0)
            std::cout << "You have obtained an whopping " << b / a << " miles to the gallon!" << "\n" << "\n";

        std::cout << "Would you like to try again? (Y/N): ";
        std::cin >> again;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be specific about what you want to ask.

Comment: You might want to work on your indentation. It'll make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Is there any way to make it so the user is given an error message when they attempt to input alphanumeric data , such as "5f" . I would only like for the user to be able to input real numbers.

Comment: Are they allowed to continue after the input is wrong?

Comment: Only if the first digit is a number, if they input a letter before a number they are presented with the "Your input must be a number...1" warning. However when they do input something like "5d" for float a they are presented with "How many miles did you travel?" immediately followed by "Your input must be a number...2".

Answer (score 0):

By default, numeric formatting starts with skipping whitespace and stops reading characters as soon as one character not matching the format of the read type is encountered. If a number could be read before such a character is encountered the read succeeds.

That applied to your example of entering `"2d"` means that `2` is successfully read as number and the next character to be read is `d`. If you want to catch that situation as an error, you can check what the next character in the stream is. If you require individual numbers to be read on lines without any spaces trailing the value, you can simply do something like this:

```
while (!(std::cin >> a) || std::cin.peek() != '\n') {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @T.Willis Consider accepting and upvoting his answer, then.